# Program in JavaScript that attempts to remove an item from an array

Tags: javascript

I need to write a program that attempts to remove an item from an array.

My code searches the array a for the item x. If x is found, its first occurrence is removed, all the elements above the position are shifted down and true is returned to indicate a successful removal. If x is not found, the array is left unchanged and false is returned. Please can anybody help me with this exercise?

What I have tried:

```js
var a = [6, 1, 5, 9];

function find() {
    let x = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += a[i];
        if (x == a[i]) {
            for (var f = i; f < a.length; f++) {
                b.push(a[f])
                alert[f]
                var index = a.indexOf(a[i])
                a.splice(index)
            }
        }
    }
}

find(a);
```

Comment: Well probably most of us could write it down for you but do you have actually any code that you write?

Comment: This site is not for solving exercises. Here is all you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: var a = [6, 1, 5, 9];
function find(){
    let x = 5;
        for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += a[i];
            if(x == a[i]){
                for (var f = i; f<a.length; f++){
                    b.push(a[f])
                    alert[f]
                    var index = a.indexOf(a[i])
                    a.splice(index)
                }
                

            }
    }
}
find(a)

Comment: Seconded @Daniel

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I do really appreciate it.Thanks a lot for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid modifying outer variables in not obvious ways. You could create a function, which directly takes array and value as arguments, removes the value and returns true/false;

`Array.splice(remove_from, elements_quantity)` method already exists. So, you have to care only about returning boolean value:

```js
var arr = [6, 1, 5, 9];

console.log( remove(arr, 6) );
console.log( remove(arr, 15) );

function remove(arr, val) {
  let index = arr.indexOf(val);  
  if( index == -1 ) return false;
  
  arr.splice(index, val);  
  return true;
}
```

And, just for fun (don't write such code):

```js
var arr = [6, 1, 5, 9];

console.log(remove(arr, 6));
console.log(remove(arr, 15));

function remove(arr, val) {
  let index = arr.indexOf(val);
  
  return !( index == -1 || !arr.splice(index, val) );
}
```

What is going on: Logical "OR" `||` operator returns the first value, which appeared to be true. If `index == -1` is true, logical "NOT" `!` will reverse it's value and return false.

In other hand, if index found, the second part of expression will be evaluated.

`arr.splice(index, val)` returns a new **array** of removed elements, which will always be true in logical context. `!( !true ) → true`